# Inserting to and searching a large amount of data in Java

Tags: java, xml

I am writing a program in Java which tracks data about baseball cards. I am trying to decide how to store the data persistently. I have been leaning towards storing the data in an XML file, but I am unfamiliar with XML APIs. (I have read some online tutorials and started experimenting with the classes in the `javax.xml` hierarchy.)

The software has to major use cases: the user will be able to add cards and search for cards.

When the user adds a card, I would like to immediately commit the data to the persistant storage. Does the standard API allow me to insert data in a random-access way (or even appending might be okay).

When the user searches for cards (for example, by a player's name), I would like to load a list from the storage without necessarily loading the whole file.

My biggest concern is that I need to store data for a large number of unique cards (in the neighborhood of thousands, possibly more). I don't want to store a list of all the cards in memory while the program is open. I haven't run any tests, but I believe that I could easily hit memory constraints.

XML might not be the best solution. However, I want to make it as simple as possible to install, so I am trying to avoid a full-blown database with JDBC or any third-party libraries.

So I guess I'm asking if I'm heading in the right direction and if so, where can I look to learn more about using XML in the way I want. If not, does anyone have suggestions about what other types of storage I could use to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I would certainly not discourage the use of XML, it does have some draw backs in your context.

*"Does the standard API allow me to insert data in a random-access way"*

Yes, in memory.  You will have to save the entire model back to file though.

*"When the user searches for cards (for example, by a player's name), I would like to load a list from the storage without necessarily loading the whole file"*

Unless you're expected multiple users to be reading/writing the file, I'd probably pull the entire file/model into memory at load and keep it there until you want to save (doing periodical writes the background is still a good idea)

*I don't want to store a list of all the cards in memory while the program is open. I haven't run any tests, but I believe that I could easily hit memory constraints*

That would be my concern to.  However, you could use a SAX parser to read the file into a custom model.  This would reduce the memory overhead (as DOM parsers can be a little greedy with memory)

*"However, I want to make it as simple as possible to install, so I am trying to avoid a full-blown database with JDBC"*

I'd do some more research in this area.  I (personally) use [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) and [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) a lot for storage of large amount of data. These are small, personal database systems that don't require any additional installation (a Jar file linked to the program) or special server/services.

They make it really easy to build complex searches across the datastore that you would otherwise need to create yourself.

If you were to use XML, I would probably do one of three things

1 - If you're going to maintain the XML document in memory, I'd get familiar with XPath
 ([simple tutorial](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFwQFjAA&url=http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/&ei=8wIjUMz3H9OgiQeosoCYDA&usg=AFQjCNGnqfjNU8axSnUoUmwLFt90KJwLWw) & [Java's API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html)) for searching.

2 - I'd create a "model" of the data using Objects to represent the various nodes, reading it in using a SAX. Writing may be a little more tricky.

3 - Use a simple SQL DB (and Object model) - it will simply the overall process (IMHO)

**Additional**

As if I hadn't dumped enough on you ;)

If you really want to XML (and again, I wouldn't discourage you from it), you might consider having a look a XML database style solution

[Apache Xindice](http://xml.apache.org/xindice/) (apparently retired)

Or you could have a look at some other people think

- [Use XML as database in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842813/use-xml-as-database-in-java)
- [Java: XML into a Database, whats the simplest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248378/java-xml-into-a-database-whats-the-simplest-way)

For example ;)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I have a `BaseballCard` class which has getters and setters for all the data (`String`s and `int`s) for a single card. I plan to use this as my model for displaying search results in my Swing GUI. I wasn't planning on storing the complete XML document in memory and would even like to avoid storing a list of all of the `BaseballCard` objects, if possible.

Comment: As you say, the writing part is where I'm having trouble. That's where I want to start so that I can have data to search. Perhaps I should just create some mock data by hand and do the reading part first as it sounds a little easier...assuming I stay with the XML idea.

Comment: Thanks for the SQL suggestions. Adding JAR files to my distribution is probably doable, but I certainly don't want to do more than that. (And I apologize for all the separate comments. I'm mostly just thinking outloud...and trying to throw some gratitude in there while I do.)

Comment: One last comment: Why do you suggest using SAX over StAX or some other API?

Comment: @Code-Guru The problem you are going to face with saving (as I see it) is that (from my experience) you need the XML in memory to update it before you can save it.  I don't prefer any particular API over another (I'm lazy, I tend to use the inbuilt API :P). I suggest using a SAX style parser because it doesn't have the memory overhead of a DOM style parser, that's all.  I think you'll generally find a well designed SQL implementation will better meet your needs, as you get random read/write access that you won't get with XML - IMHO

Comment: And probably better search speeds...I will take a look at the SQL databases you linked when I have a chance.

Comment: I ended up using HSQLDB for my project. Thanks for the suggestion.